# advanced Search (checkboxes and selection)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem with my advanced search. 
Essentially, its an advanced search for bands (name, style, bandpicture by checkboxes (checked: have a bandpicture))

Here is the code.

result.html.erb

```
<table >
  <colgroup>
     <col width="250" />
   </colgroup>
<tr>
 <td> 
<label for="name">Filter</label></br>
   <%= form_tag band_path do %>

      <label for="Style">Style</label></br>
         <%= select_tag :style_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Style.all, :id, :name, params[:style_id]), include_blank: true, class: "form-control" %>
        <br>
      </br>

      <%= check_box_tag 'options[]', "picture" %>

      <%= button_to '#', class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
      <%= t(:find) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    </td>

    <td>
  <div>
    <% @bands.each do |band|%>
      <div class="top-bar">
       <div class="center">
        <div class="info">
         <div class="name"><%=band.id %></div>
         <div> <%= band.zip %>, <%= band.city %> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          <table>
           <tr>
            <td>Styles</td>
            <td>
              <% band.styles.each do |s| %>
                  <%= s.style.name %>
              <% end %>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
<% end %>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

models band.rb

```
  def self.search1(style_id)
      Profile.joins("...").where("style_id = ?", style_id)  
  end
```

controller.

```
def searchresult
   if params[:style_id].present?
      @bands = Band.search1 params[:style_id]

    elsif params[:options]
   Band.where(:options => @filtered_options)

else
  @bands = Band.all
end
```

end

The searchresult don't show the result of the checkboxes and I have this errors:

```
undefined method `search1' for #<Class:0x00000008eb5548>
```